# Elementary $2$-equivalence $X=(A, <^X)$ with $N=(\mathbb{N}, <)$. Conclusions.

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

> Let structure $X=(A,<^X)$ be linear order on $A$ such that it is
>   elementary $2$-equiavalent to $N=(\mathbb{N}, <)$. Can we conlude
>   that:   (a) $A$ is infinity.   (b) $A$ has an the smallest element
>   (c) Each element of $A$ has only finitely many elements lower from
>   self.

I try to solve this, I ask you for checking my reasoning.
First of all, what does it mean that $A\equiv_2B$ ?  We know that $A$ and $B$ can't be distinguished each other using at most $2$ (it is about depth) quantifiers.

(a) $A$ is infinite. Yes, because we know that for $N$: $\forall_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \exists_{m\in \mathbb{N}}m>n$. We used only two quantifiers, hence $X$ is also infinite.
(b) The same as (a) because $\exists_{m\in \mathbb{N}}\forall_{n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus \{m\}} m<n$
(c) I think that answer is negative.   It is sufficient to show that for $N$ number two is not sufficient to express property (c).

To my eye, we may show that $(\mathbb{R}, <)$ is not distinguishable from $(\mathbb{N}, <)$ - it is easy to show strategy for duplication - only two stages.  Now, because $(\mathbb{R}, <)$ don't satisfy property (c) and is not distinguishable from $(\mathbb{N}, <)$. Consequently, $N$ can't be concluded in our task.

Can you check my solution ?

Comment: Your strategy is sound but $(\mathbb{R},<)$ is not elementary $2$-equivalent to $N$ since for instance it does not satisfy $(b)$.

Comment: You are right. So (a) and (b) are ok. How to solve (c) ?

Comment: That depends on what you know about model theory. I am trying to find something easy to introduce.

Comment: Ok, so I wait for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a (fairly) elementary solution to (c): consider $A={\bf N}\sqcup {\bf Z}$ (where ${\bf Z}$ is put after ${\bf N}$). It is easy to check that $A$ is elementarily equivalent to ${\bf N}$ using Ehrenfeucht-Fraïssé games, and it clearly has elements with infinitely many elements below.

Comment: I thought about such sum. Yes, it is obvious that there are elements that have infinitely many elements below (each integer number).  However, I have some doubts. Can we talk about it on chat?

Comment: @HaskellFun: I'm not sure if I will be available, but you can try. You can also ask for clarification here.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: the following answer is flawed, specifically the "basic result" is false. I still leave it because there are relevant comments below.**

There is a notion that is relevant here, but I cannot remember its name. I think it is $\infty$-something, at least in french. It might be a little overkill, but not too much I beleive.

Anyway, let's say that two structures $\mathcal{M},\mathcal{S}$ with base sets $M,S$ are $\infty$-equivalent if there is a set $\mathcal{F}$ of partial isomorphisms $\mathcal{M} \rightarrow \mathcal{S}$ (that is maps from a substructure of $\mathcal{M}$ onto a substructure of $\mathcal{N}$ that are monomorphisms) such that $\forall \sigma \in \mathcal{F}, \forall s \in S, \exists m \in M, \exists \sigma' \in  \mathcal{F}, \sigma \cup \{(m,s)\}\subset \sigma'$. So any element of $\mathcal{F}$ be extended in $\mathcal{F}$ by any value in $S$.

The basic result here is:

-Any two $\infty$-equivalent structures are elementary equivalent (thus, elementary $2$-equivalent). **this is actually false**

This is proved by induction on the complexity of formulas, using the fact that the variables in formulas belong to a finite set and that finite substructures in one structure have isomorphic counterparts in the other because of the existence of $\mathcal{F}$. I leave it to you to prove them, but I can edit with details if needed.

Now, regarding your problem, define $\mathcal{M} : = (\mathbb{N} \times \{0;1\},\prec)$,  $\prec$ is $ \{((m,t),(n,t)) \ | \ m <n \in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{((m,0),(n,1)) \ | \ m,n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. $\mathcal{M}$ is the sum of $\mathcal{N}$ with itself (this is a standard order-theory construction), and it is well-ordered.

Moreover, $\mathcal{M}$ is $\infty$-equivalent to $\mathcal{N}$.

Indeed, the set $\mathcal{F}$ consisting of all isomorphisms between finite substructures of $\mathbb{N} \times \{0;1\}$ and finite substructures of $\mathcal{N}$ of same cardinal satisfies the property. Hence $\mathcal{M}$ is elementary $2$-equivalent to $\mathcal{N}$ despite the fact that in it $(0,1)$ has infinitely many elements below itself.

---

If you're into model theory, you will often come across this fact that non-uniform finiteness cannot be captured by elementary equivalency (let alone weaker forms of equivalency). This is strongly linked to a fundamental result in model theory called the compactness theorem, which I suggest you look into.

Comment: Is it possible to solve (c) in simpler way ? I know compactness theorem.

Comment: Well, how would you use it to find an elementary extension $(\mathcal{M},\rho)$ of $\mathbf{N}$ with an element $\omega$ strictly superior to any $\rho(n), n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: I don't understand you, be more simple please

Comment: @HaskellFun What nombre is asking is (essentially) the following: can you use Compactness to show that there is some structure $X$ in the relevant language such that (i) $X$ satisfies all the sentences that $(\mathbb{N}, <)$ does, but (ii) there is some element of $X$ with infinitely many things below it? This would show that (c) fails . . . HINT: Think about expanding the language with a new constant symbol $c$; what things do you want to say about $c$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I don't understand why you don't say anything about number $2$. it is important here

Comment: @HaskellFun By number 2, do you mean (ii) - that there is some element of $X$ with infinitely many things below it? If so, yes, I was leaving this as an exercise for you. Think about what properties the new element, $c$, should have in order to be useful to you . . .

Comment: @HaskellFun or do you mean why don't I talk about 2-quantifier depth? That's because I'm giving you a hint about how to prove something **stronger**: that no first-order theory *of any depth at all* can do this. To be honest, I don't see any way to show that (c) fails without showing this stronger fact.

Comment: Ok, I think about it and give you a sign about my conclusions.

Comment: yes, I think that you did mean someting stronger, more general

Comment: Hmm, maybe $X=(\mathbb{Q}\cup\{0\}, <)$ ? It has the smallest element $0$ and there exists element (for example $1$) that has infinitely many elements smaller . Then $X$ and $N$ are not distinguishable and $X$ doesn't satisfy property (c). So this property can't be expressed in FO. OK ?

Comment: No, $X$ and $\mathbb{N}$ **are** distinguishable, indeed by a sentence of depth two. Do you see why?

Comment: @nombre: I'm not sure if I'm reading you right. Are you suggesting that ${\bf N}$ is equivalent to ${\bf N}\sqcup {\bf N}$? Because that is not true: in the latter, we have two elements without predecessors.

Comment: @tomasz: My  answer is erroneous indeed. I'll try to correct it when I have time today because I think this notion can be used here, and if not I will delete it.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, I did mean $X=(\mathbb{Q_{\ge 0}}, <)$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, when it comes to distinguishability $(\mathbb{Q}\cup \{0\}, <)$ - I think that: $\forall_n \exists_m m < n$.

Comment: For me, $(X=(\mathbb{Q}_{\ge 0}, <)$ is not distinguishable from $N$ in two stages (with depth equals to two)